# *** Android NDK: Aborting. . Stop

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to compile my code using android ndk. I am using windows machine.
My android.mk is as follows.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
SHELL := PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin /bin/bash

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := streamer_native_manager
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := streamer-native-manager.c gstrtpchannels.c skyrtpL16pay.c skyrtpL16depay.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := gstrtpchannels.h skyrtpL16pay.h skyrtpL16depay.h
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And in `build.gradle`, I have made following configuration,

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        java.srcDirs += 'src/main/jni/src'
        assets.srcDirs += 'src/main/jni/assets'
    }
}
```

And for compiling in same file,

```
task nativeBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
            def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.ndkFolder
            commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
                    '-C', file('src\\main\\jni').absolutePath,
                    '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                    'all'
        }

        task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
            def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.ndkFolder
            commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
                    '-C', file('src\\main\\jni').absolutePath,
                    'clean'
        }

        clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn nativeBuild
        }
```

But when I do clean project, I am getting following error,

`*** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:cleanNative'.

> Process 'command 'AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

I am using windows machine, So can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does your `-j` configuration get passed to the clean task? Could be https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/198

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new problem? This sounds like the development environment was not properly setup because you are just cleaning the code. If this error occurred when building, I would say to look at your code. But since it happens when cleaning, it almost has to be the development environment.

Did you touch your path lately?

You should make sure that Cygwin is on the path.

Comment: No, I have just installed ndk from android download manager, and tried to clean the project, I only changed, `commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
                    '-C', file('src\\main\\jni').absolutePath,
                    'clean'` slashes to match it with windows, But If I revert it back to / still it does not work.

Comment: Do I need to install Cygwin terminal?

Comment: I am not sure what the situation is with Android Studio because I do development with Eclipse, but yes I do need Cygwin to compile NDK code

Comment: Ok I will try installing cygwin and try.

Comment: Cygwin is on but where to mention path?

Comment: Cygwin needs to be on your system path. For instance, if you open a command prompt and try to run the man command, it should run. It should not give you a file not found exception

Comment: Done but still same problem

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio after you added to the path?

Comment: The last thing I would do is to try running ndk-build.cmd from the command prompt (run from the ndk folder). If that works, then it might be something with your project after all.